# fullcalendar scheduler sources

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I am supposed to see 2 columns,'Room A' and 'Room B'. However, I can see only one column without either. please let me know what I missed. 
Thank you in advance

```
<script>
  $(function() {

      // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        // put your options and callbacks here
          defaultView: 'agendaDay',
          events: [
            // events go here
          ],
        Resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor:'green'}
          ]
      })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Resources is capitalized. You need to change it to lower case

```
 resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor:'green'}
          ]
```